# Text processing: porting Perl scripts to Python

Tags: python, perl, substitution, text-processing

I have developed a number of scripts in Perl to process text files (basically, I need to make nonstandard conversions from html to LaTeX). I was wondering what is the best way to translate into Python 3 a script that does a very high number of substitution one after another on a file (all together or line by line). In Perl I have, for example:

```
$file =~ s/.../.../g;
$file =~ s/.../.../g;
$file =~ s/.../.../sg;
$file =~ s{...}{...}sge;
etc.
print $file;
```

Am I correct in assuming that the (best) way to do the same in Python is the following? I don't think it is appropriate to compile the regex expression, as there are so many different involved.

```
import re
etc.
file = re.sub(r"...",r"...",file)
file = re.sub(r"...",r"...",file)
file = re.sub(r"...",r"...",file)
file = re.sub(r"...",r"...",file)
etc.
print(file)
```

I was also wondering what is the best way to alternate line based substitution and file based substitution in Python (in Perl I can just turn on/off the switch 's' as in the example).